# Does a CAN bus DBC file require a 1:1 mapping from CAN ID to message type?

Tags: can

I'm trying to learn more about DBC files and am having trouble a few things that I was hoping people here could help with. My questions are kind of two sides of the same coin:

1. Can the messages only be identified using the CAN ID, or is it possible to use DBC files to parse the data for the message type. For example the two messages have the same CAN ID but their payload should be parsed differently based on byte #1
2. Is it possible to mask the CAN ID to parse multiple different CAN IDs the same way? For instance, if I have 4 temp sensors sending their temperature, and the last 4 bits of the CAN ID are used to identify the sensor. Do I need to enter each message 4 times in the DBC or can I somehow tell the parser to parse just the top 7 bits, and use the last 4 bits as a device number field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. After the signal name you can specify `m <value of multiplexer>` or mark a signal as the multiplexer with `M`. You can have only one multiplexer per message (and since the signal are mapped to at most one message, the multiplexer signal to use is derived automatically).
2. No, templating is not allowed.

See http://mcu.so/Microcontroller/Automotive/dbc-file-format-documentation_compress.pdf for further information (page 8, paragraph 8.2) for the first bullet.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where this information may be published? I've had a difficult time finding any detailed documentation on DBC files

Comment: @Otus see edit.